# How to convert Spark data frame to Pandas and back in Kedro?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, kedro

I'm trying to understand what is the optimal way in Kedro to convert Spark dataframe coming out of one node into Pandas required as input for another node without creating a redundant conversion step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kedro currently supports 2 strategies for that:

#### Using [Transcoding](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04_user_guide/04_data_catalog.html#transcoding-datasets) feature

This requires one to define two `DataCatalog` entries for the same dataset, working with the same file in a common format (Parquet, JSON, CSV, etc.), in your `catalog.yml`:

```
my_dataframe@spark:
  type: kedro.contrib.io.pyspark.SparkDataSet
  filepath: data/02_intermediate/data.parquet

my_dataframe@pandas:
  type: ParquetLocalDataSet
  filepath: data/02_intermediate/data.parquet
```

And then use them in the pipeline like this:

```py
Pipeline([
    node(my_func1, "spark_input", "my_dataframe@spark"),
    node(my_func2, "my_dataframe@pandas", "output"),
])
```

In this case, `kedro` understands that `my_dataframe` is the same dataset in both cases and resolves the node execution order properly. At the same time, `kedro` would use the `SparkDataSet` implementation for saving and `ParquetLocalDataSet` for loading, so the first node should output `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`, while the second node would receive a `pandas.Dataframe`.

#### Using [Pandas to Spark](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kedro.contrib.decorators.pandas_to_spark.html) and [Spark to Pandas](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kedro.contrib.decorators.spark_to_pandas.html) node decorators

**Note:** `Spark <-> Pandas` in-memory conversion is [notorious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536675/3364156) for its memory demands, so this is a viable option only if the dataframe is known to be small.

One can decorate the node as per the docs:

```py
from spark import get_spark
from kedro.contrib.decorators import pandas_to_spark

@pandas_to_spark(spark_session)
def my_func3(data):
    data.show() # data is pyspark.sql.DataFrame
```

Or even the whole pipeline:

```py
Pipeline([
    node(my_func4, "pandas_input", "some_output"),
    ...
]).decorate(pandas_to_spark)
```